# how to display a random point every second in kivy

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I try to display a random point every second in kivy.
Here is my code. I know how to display the point, an ellipse in this case. But I don't know how to make its position to update every second.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Ellipse
import time
import numpy as np

class RandomPoint(Widget):

def __init__(self,dimension):
    super(RandomPoint,self).__init__()
    self.d = dimension
    self.point = Ellipse(pos=list(np.random.randint(0,1000,2)),size = (self.d, self.d))

def update(self, *args):
    self.point = Ellipse(pos=list(np.random.randint(0,1000,2)),size = (self.d, self.d))

class TimeApp(App):
def build(self):
    wid = Widget()
    with wid.canvas:
        p = RandomPoint(25)
        Clock.schedule_interval(p.update, 1)
    return wid

TimeApp().run()
```

How would you do that ?

Comment: I think your `update()` method could just be `self.point.pos = list(np.random.randint(0,1000,2))`.

Comment: To add with John's comment, I think you should also replace this line `p = RandomPoint(25)` to this `self.p = RandomPoint(25)` and this `Clock.schedule_interval(p.update, 1)` to this `Clock.schedule_interval(self.p.update, 1)`.

Comment: Thank you, it does the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the `Clock.schedule_interval` call in the canvas block won't satisfy the requirement of these calls to happen in a canvas block. They are executed later, when the code exited the `with` block long ago. What you can do is use the same construction, but inside both `__init__` and `update`, around your `Ellipse` instructions.

Also, at no point do you add your `RandomPoint` widget, to your root widget, so it won't be visible at all, whatever happens with its instructions.

```py
class RandomPoint(Widget):
    def __init__(self,dimension):
        super(RandomPoint,self).__init__()
        self.d = dimension
        self.points = []
        with self.canvas:
            self.point.append(Ellipse(pos=list(np.random.randint(0,1000,2)),size = (self.d, self.d)))

def update(self, *args):
    with self.canvas:
        self.points.append(Ellipse(pos=list(np.random.randint(0,1000,2)),size = (self.d, self.d)))

class TimeApp(App):
    def build(self):
        wid = Widget()
        p = RandomPoint(25)
        wid.add_widget(p)
        Clock.schedule_interval(p.update, 1)
        return wid

TimeApp().run()
```